# Dictionary Size Change During Iteration Error

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, iteration, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I'm writing a code to delete some items in a dictionary by selection, and even use a copy of the dictionary to prevent changing its size during iteration, but I keep getting this error:

> 'RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration'

```
import copy
word = {'a':{'aa':{'aaa', 'aab'}, \
             'ab':{'aaa', 'aab'}}, \
        'b':{'ba':{'aaa', 'aab'}, \
             'bb':{'aaa', 'aab'}}, \
        'c':{'ca':{'aaa', 'aab'}, \
             'cb':{'aaa', 'aab'}}}
wordCopy = copy.copy(word)
for item in word.keys():
    for k in word[item].keys():
        print(k)
        print('Enter del to delete this item:')
        deleteCertificate = input()
        if deleteCertificate == 'del':
            del wordCopy[item][k]
word = wordCopy
print(word)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to your `copy`. It is in fact just a `shallow copy`. From the docs:

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.

So when you shallow copy the dictionary it still has references to the original dict. You will see this, if after your error, you print out `word` you will notice that an element has been deleted from it.

Instead you need a `deep copy`. Again from the docs:

> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

You can avoid your error if you replace the line:

`wordCopy = copy.copy(word)`

with:

`wordCopy = copy.deepcopy(word)`

I also suggest you read the [docs on copy](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html) in full.

Answer (score 1):

Your `wordCopy` is separate from `word`, but `wordCopy[item]` is the same object as `word[item]` because `copy.copy` is a shallow copy.

You can make a deep copy, or you could just create a new empty object, and on inverted condition insert there items that need to be retained, without modifying the original `word` at all.